# Angular to use Rails templates + Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Rails provide a strong template engine out of box and i like it. I was wondering if there is any  way to use it? So maybe angular templates can be wrapped inside rails that lives in our views directory. We can call it metatemplates.

So instead of my angular templates living in asset directory which i feel is not a good way?

Also i need to make use of rails routes inside my angular at some point. For example Signout functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you could let Ruby serve up angular templates.  Ultimately Angular is requesting a resource from the server via a url, and expects it to be an html fragment.  If Angular is requesting from Rails, then you could use Rails functionality to serve up the html fragment (ie template).  So you could write your angular templates as a Rails partial using erb or haml, which Rails would then serve up as html to the requester.

As a side note, it gets complicated to separate concerns doing this approach.  Keep it clear in your mind what Rails needs to do as an application server, and what Rails needs to do as an application service.  The application server needs to serve up the Angular application (i.e. js and html that will be managed by Angular on the client side).  The application service needs to serve json that will be consumed by Angular.